# What does sed's -E option do?

Tags: sed

I found how to swap the first word with the third word in a line using sed, but I do not know what is `-E` from the syntax: `sed -E 'regular expression'`. What is the meaning of `'-E'`? Thanks! Moreover, can I apply the changes to the file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**-E** is for compatibility with BSD. It's the same as **-r** or **--regexp-extended** — use extended regular expressions in the script.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3139925/3292582

For applying the changes you can either

- use a temporary file,
- **-i** option if your `sed` version supports it (GNU `sed`—the default on Linux—and BSD `sed`—which is also installed on OSX—both support it)
- **ed** command, which has a different command set though.

Comment: Or if you are using GNU `sed`, you can use option `-i` (perhaps the best reason for using the GNU version)

Comment: @Philippos BSD sed, and probably others, also has it.

Comment: It is also the option that will be in the next release of the POSIX standard for enabling extended regular expression processing. One could also argue that GNU `sed` added it for symmetry with `grep`, which has the same option for doing the same thing.